# Undefined Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
  public onChange(event: Event) {
    let files = event.target['files'];
    let list: string[];
    console.log(files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = () => {
          let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;   
          list.push(infoFile);         
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log(list);
    let preview = document.querySelector('img');
    preview.src = list[0];
  };
```

I have method in my component.ts when i click input type="file" called medthod onChange() but when left loop for in console i have message that array is undefined. I check that fileReader.result is not empty Why is this happening? How to solve this problem some idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to initialize the list first:

```
let list: string[] = [];
```

when you do just

```
let list: string[]
```

you only tell the compiler that this variable will be an array of strings. But at runtime it is undefined, because you didn't initialized it anyway.

Comment: @Matiusz.V7 maybe you know how to use this Array  outside the loop for when I using list[0] i have errror that is undefined

Comment: in console i have something like this [ ] 0:" data:image...." 1:"data.image2...."

Comment: Undefined from list[0] is only when list is empty. You may want to check previously if list.length > 0. Apart from that you should be able to use it like a normal list.

Comment: []
0
:
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA.....
1
:
"data:image/jpeg;base64.....
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)                                                                                                         I have something like this length = 2

Comment: maybe try to ask another question with more detailed description about your problem.