# Weird representation of Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I declared an array as:

```
list: string[] = [];
```

and I push it like:

```
let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
      this.list.push(infoFile);
```

When I used console log, I got something weird

```
    []
0
:
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA.....
1
:
"data:image/jpeg;base64.....
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Why I dont get something like :

```
[ "str1", "str2", .. ]
```

When I use list[0] I get error that it is undefined. How to use this data ?

Comment: `infoFile` isn't `"str1"`.  It's a long data string.  Why do you expect it to be `"str1"`?

Comment: @recursive i use typeof(infoFile) and return string

Comment: Well, yes.  `"data:image/jpeg;base64,...` *is* a string.

Comment: @recursive what does it mean i have empty array but length is 2. I don't understand

Comment: It looks like you just have an array with length 2.  I don't know what you mean by "When I use list[0] i have error that is undefined".

Comment: let preview = document.querySelector('img');
    preview.src = list[0];                                                                                                    when I use this i have error also when console.log(list[0]) i have output that is undefined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571335/undefined-array in this is all code for comonent.ts

Comment: Maybe is called destructor after exit from function. I set array as global variable

Comment: @recursive Do you have idea how to properly use this array

Comment: If you want help with your problem, please produce a single straight-forward reproduction of the problem.  As it stands now, I can't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
let infoFile: string = fileReader.result;
this.list.push(infoFile);
```

You *think* `fileReader.result` is a *string*. It is actually an ArrayBuffer in your case : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result

Hence you get items like

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA.....
length: 1
```

Instead of

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA....."
```

Comment: I use typeof for infoFile and return string. I don't rember add " in the end of string. InfoFile is a very long string maybe string has some limit and that is the problem that i can't read list[i]. It's a link to question that contains all example.

Comment: I use that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL. Documentation say that "At that time, the result attribute contains  the data as a URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string."